# loading beans from XML (programmatic way) does not work

Tags: java, xml, spring, component-scan

After loading beans using XmlBeanDefinitionReader's loadBeanDefinitions method , Auto scan feature of spring xml does not work as all the beans mentioned in the xml gets created but the beans which are marked by @Component to auto detect are not created.why Xsd validation is not working ?

code that i am writing is

```
 XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beanDefinitionRegistry);

 reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);

 reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

 ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).refresh();
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the error trace along with code?

Comment: It does not give any error. 
here my problem is all the beans that are defined in xml are created in application context but the ones with @component tag does not get created. moreover their life cycle events do not trigger.

Comment: show us your config xml. Moreover confirm if it contains `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.something"/>`

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.prashant.ext" />

and the classes with @component tag are in packages under "com.prashant.ext" packages.